# File change notifications for macOS using C++

Tags: c++, macos, core-foundation

I'm coding a macOS launch daemon (in C++) and I need to know when a certain file on local disk was changed. Does the OS provide such notifications?

PS. I was trying to avoid polling that file for a change every N seconds in a loop.

Comment: MacOS uses the BSD-derived kqueue API to provide filesystem event notifications. You probably want to sniff out `NOTE_CLOSE_WRITE` events.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Thanks, that sounds promising. Although I'm new to Linux programming. Can you give me a code example how to use that NOTE_CLOSE_WRITE event?

Comment: Your gaze towards Linux programming will not help you much, since MacOS is not based on Linux, but on FreeBSD. I also have Linux background, but when I was looking to implement the equivalent of Linux's inotify API on BSD, I had no issues locating the relevant technical documentation for BSD's kqueue API, and implementing it. I found the BSD manpages, plus search engine queries, to be sufficient enough to get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to achieve some success in monitoring file changes with kqueue, as proposed by Sam in comments, I would recommend to use other approach.

Try to use the [FSEvents API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events). It is much more convenient than old-style kqueue stuff and could be easy integrated into [c++ code](https://gist.github.com/josephg/6c078a241b0e9e538ac04ef28be6e787). It is also from the CoreServices Framework, so it [could be safely used in daemons](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html) on macOS (search by "Daemon-Safe Frameworks")

The most important part of it is to [subscribe](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443980-fseventstreamcreate) to the events of interest, to have a separate event loop, and to release all these things correctly once the job is done.

From the first look it seems you can make use of [kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1455361-fseventstreameventflags/kfseventstreameventflagitemmodified) flag.

In both ways you will need to clarify for yourself, what kind of "file was changed" definitions are interesting for you and adjust the event flags accordingly.

There is no NOTE_CLOSE_WRITE on macOS, by the way, however there are some [other](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/kqueue.2.html) useful flags for your case.

Comment: Very nice info. Thanks.